# A list of videos from Youtube with 400 ERROR CODE

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using Youtube API in my app, i'm trying to get a list of videos from Youtube, it's work fine, but it's limit to 48 videos in one list for some reason, when I'm trying to get more than 48 videos in one list, i'm getting  **400 ERROR CODE**, Here's my code:

```
public void Load(final Context context, int start, int end, int category, LoaderVideoListener listener) {
    try {
        mVideosNames.clear();
        mVideos.clear();
        mCategory = category;
        mStart = start;
        mEnd = end;
        mListener = listener;

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference dataRef = database.getReference();
        String child = "Category";
        if (mCategory == 1) {
            child = "category1";
        } else if (mCategory == 2) {
            child = "category2";
        } else {
            child += category;
        }
        dataRef.child(child).orderByChild("index").startAt(start).endAt(end).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    StringBuilder videoIds = new StringBuilder();

                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        videoIds.append(data.child("YTId").getValue()).append(",");
                    }

                    Network net = new Network();
                    net.Request(context, URL_1 + videoIds + URL_2, new RequestJsonListiner() {
                        @Override
                        public void OnResponse(String json, boolean isError, String errorDetails) {
                            if (!isError) {
                                try {
                                    ParseJsonToVideoYT(json);
                                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                    handleCallBack.obtainMessage(1, e1.getMessage()).sendToTarget();
                                }
                            } else
                                handleCallBack.obtainMessage(1, errorDetails).sendToTarget();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                handleCallBack.obtainMessage(1, databaseError.getMessage()).sendToTarget();

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

400 error means bad request so there's something wrong with your field parameters. Also, note that maxResults in [Youtube API list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) has a maximum value of 50.